# I'm facing issue to find element in the new window after performing a switchTo(new Handle) in IE Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting the values of account from the main function. 
I think the element is inside a frame. Could you please help me with it.

The code that I'm using is

```
public static void FSVLogin(WebDriver driver){

    try{

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginMode_6']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnLaunch']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        switchwindow(driver);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);

    }

}



public static void switchwindow(WebDriver driver){

    //Get all window handles
    Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    //count the handles Here count is=2
    System.out.println("Count of windows:"+allHandles.size());  

  //Get current handle or default handle
    String currentWindowHandle = allHandles.iterator().next();
    System.out.println("currentWindow Handle"+currentWindowHandle);

  //Remove first/default Handle
    allHandles.remove(allHandles.iterator().next());

  //get the last Window Handle
    String lastHandle = allHandles.iterator().next();
    System.out.println("last window handle"+lastHandle);

  //switch to second/last window, because we know there are only two    windows 1-parent window 2-other window(ad window)
    driver.switchTo().window(lastHandle);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

}


public static void LoadAccountCase(WebDriver driver,String account,String caseid){


try{
    System.out.println("inside account case load function");

    //WebElement card=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtCardNumber']"));
    String id="txtCardNumber";
    waitForPageLoad(driver,id);
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtCardNumber")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtCardNumber")).sendKeys(account);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element in the new window is inside a Frame then you first need to switch to the frame and then locate the element.

```
frame = driver.findElement(by.id("id of the frame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

/*To switch back to the page use*/
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```